# how to read the fileset of the specific column in unix

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file like this,

```
Filesystem    State   1024-blocks      Used       Avail   Capacity  Mounted on
$ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED    71686344    58788360    12897984   82%    /deleteme
```

In this file i want to read the 1st column and 5th column without using grep command

i tried this command,but it shows istead of 5th coloumn it shows 6th column output

```
 df -k DELETEME | awk '{print $1 $5 }'
FilesystemAvail
$ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED82%.
```

expected output is

```
Avail
12897984
```

Comment: Which of the columns has a blank value? (there are 7 column headers and 6 values)

Comment: In 6 values, one value i.e., $ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED is returned with out space. Values returned from df -k command for two columns  was                               $ZPMON.DELETEME        
         STARTED  whereas  df -k DELETEME returns value  $ZPMON.DELETEMESTARTED instead of two columns.

Answer (score 1):

With single GNU **`df`** command:

```
df -k --output=avail DELETEME
```

Comment: gettting below error for above command    df -k --output=avail DELETEME
df: illegal option -- -
usage: df [-k] [file_system ...]

Comment: that's GNU implementation

Comment: This has nothing to do with the shell you're running. Download GNU df, install it, then call it.